# Could not parse the remainder: '' from '' error while run forloop in template Django values query set

Tags: django-templates

**View.py**

```
def InvoicePage(request):
        
        invoiceItem_id=InvoiceItem.objects.values("invoices__id","invoices__invoice_no","invoices__create_by","invoices__create_at","invoices__status").annotate(gst_total = Sum((F('quantity')*F('items_price__price')*F('items_price__gst__gst')/100)),total =Sum(F('quantity')*F('items_price__price')))
        context = {
                    'invoiceItem_id':invoiceItem_id,
                }
        return render(request,"base/invoice/table.html",context)
```

**Template**

```
 for i in invoiceItem_id %}
                <tr>

                    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td><!-- for index number -->
                     <td>{{i['invoices__invoice_no']}}</td>
  </tr> 
            {% endfor %}
```

**Getting Error while run the forloop Error = Could not parse the remainder: '['invoices__invoice_no']' from 'i['invoices__invoice_no']'**